# Python not too hard, just struggling with variable

Tags: python, random, tags

**Code:**

```
loop = 0

def main():
  while loop == 0:
    Num = input("Please Enter The Number Of People That Need The Cocktails ")
    print()
    print(" Type END if you want to end the program ")
    print()
    for count in range (Num):
      with open("Cocktails.txt",mode="w",encoding="utf-8") as myFile:
          print()
          User = input("Please Enter What Cocktails You Would Like ")
          if User == "END":
            print(Num, "Has Been Written To The File ")
            exit()
          else:
            myFile.write(User+"/n")
            myFile.write(Num+"/n")
            print()
            print(User, "Has Been Written To The File ")
```

**Error:**

> line 9, in main for count in range (Num): TypeError: 'str' object
>   cannot be interpreted as an integer

I'm trying to set the variable as the number of times it will repeat how many cocktails they would like.

**Example:**

```
How many cocktails ?  6
```

The script should then ask the user to enter what cocktails he wants six times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, `input()` returns a string by default. Change `Num` to:

```
Num = int(input("Please Enter The Number Of People That Need The Cocktails "))
```

Also

```
MyFile.write(Num + "\n")
```

should read:

```
MyFile.write(str(Num) + "\n")
```

And just for the record, you can replace:

```
loop = 0
while (loop == 0):
```

with:

```
while True:
```

Comment: @Alex Thornton, sorry :/ I had started writing my solution as soon as the question was posted, therefore my browser refreshed the page only when I had posted. Don't quite understand why yours wasn't accepted, judging by the timestamp, it was posted much earlier... Also while(True):

Comment: @Alex Thornton I don't see why, sadly, your answer was posted earlier, but I put just as much effort into my post as you did in yours. You're free to copypasta my while(True): recommendation, but I don't really want to remove my work :(

Comment: @Alex Thornton, I hadn't seen your post until I had posted and by the next refresh, my answer had been accepted. I do understand your frustration, besides, muh while loop makes better code, yes, it's marginal, but doesn't that make my answer the better one?

Comment: @Alex Thornton, I thought SO liked posting helpful little tit-bits of information along with the main answer? But honestly,enough of the petty arguing, as you said, there are plenty of questions in which one may gain reputation. This is wasting your time, as well as mine.

Comment: @Alex Thornton In which case, I'll upvote your answer, if it eases the pain caused

Answer (score 1):

Cast `int()` on your `input` to make `Num` a workable integer. This has to be done because in Python 3, `input` always returns a string:

```
Num = int(input("Please Enter The Number Of People That Need The Cocktails "))
```

With your code in it's current state, you are trying to construct a `range` from a string, which will not work at all as `range()` requires an integer.

---

**EDIT:**

Now you must replace:

```
myFile.write(Num+"/n")
```

with:

```
myFile.write(str(Num)+"/n")
```

`Num` is an integer at this point, so you must explicitly make a string to concatenate it with a newline character.

Comment: @user352198 To fix that, just do instead `str(Num)+'\n'`. `Num` is an integer at this point, so you must explicitly make a string to concatenate it with a newline character.

Comment: @user3525198 Have you even tried to debug your script?

Comment: where abouts  do i put str(Num)+'\n'

Comment: @user3525198 use it to replace `Num+"/n"` on line 18.

Comment: syntax bro put it like this

Comment: i just need the user input for Num   and for the program to recognise it at    for count in range (Num):   and to set the the range as the variable

Comment: @user3525198 Editing answer to show you what I mean. If I have been of assistance to you, feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Upvoted for being the first poster with a correct answer

Comment: @Alex Thornton, oh well, something new learnt everyday on SO, regardless of whether or not it is technical :)

Comment: @Alex Thornton I'm posting from my Windows Phone 8, HTC 8S is the model name, IE 11 is the browser.